# In simple language, if I install and use Sphinx (GPLv2) on my co-located server for a commercial LAMP website do I need to buy a license?

Tags: licensing, sphinxsearch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Do I have to license [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) for a commercial website?  I don't need to modify the code... just use it with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

No.

From: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/licensing.html

> An important instance when a commercial license is not required generally occurs when one uses Sphinx for a Web site or a hosted service. For example, even if one provides a paid search services to their end users, a commercial license would not be required